# Non repeating element

Tags: python

Why this code is not working
everything looks good

````
string = '151256'
flag = True
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(len(string)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        elif string[i] == string[j]:
            flag = False
            
    if flag == True:
        print(i)```
````

Comment: *"is not working"*: in what way? What is expected? What is this code trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of the code is to get the indecies of unique elements then you should reset the flag to True after the start of the loop "on every charachter" like this

```
string = '151256'
for i in range(len(string)):
    flag = True

    for j in range(len(string)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        elif string[i] == string[j]:
            flag = False
            
    if flag == True:
        print(i)
```

If you want to print the actual non repeating characters you shoud edit the last line to be `print string[i]`

Answer (score 1):

As @AhmedIbrahem mentioned, you have to 'reset' the flag to `True` during each iteration of the parent for loop.

In addition, a string in Python is an iterable object, meaning you do not have to use `for i in range(iterable_object):...`, you can just do `for i in iterable_object:...`.

If you also wish to have access to a 'count' or 'index', you can use Python's `enumerate(iterable_object)` function, which returns another iterable object filled with 2-item tuples, where the first item is the index, and the second item is the item at that index in the original iterable object.

In your example this could look like:

```
string = "151256"
flag = True
for i_count, i in enumerate(string):
    flag = True
    for j_count, j in enumerate(string):
        if i_count == j_count:
            continue
        elif i == j:
            flag = False
    if flag:
        print(i_count)
```

Also, since `flag` is a boolean value, the comparison `if flag == True:...` can be simplified to `if flag:...` (since that's basically saying `if True:...`).